# C# Source Generator should refresh/delete emited files

Tags: msbuild, roslyn, .net-5, csproj, sourcegenerators

I created a Source Generator to extend (partial) classes which fulfill certain criteria. To check and view the generated code I enabled the emission of these files by adding the following to my project:

```
    <PropertyGroup>
        <EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>true</EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>
        <CompilerGeneratedFilesOutputPath>Generated</CompilerGeneratedFilesOutputPath>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

This works as long as I don't do refactoring - like renaming a class. Because for every class a file is generated but not removed when I rename the "source" class.

So I added the following code to clean all generated files (on clean and rebuild)

```
    <Target Name="CleanSourceGeneratedFiles" AfterTargets="Clean">
        <RemoveDir Directories="Generated" />
    </Target>
```

However then every second rebuild fails with:
`Error  CS2001  Source file 'xyz.generated.cs' could not be found.`

So I'm looking for another way to keep my generated sources up to date, where the project not only compiles every second try.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: @saarrrr I switched to not explicitly generate files since you can still access them via the IDE

Answer (score 6):

Try this. It works for me.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>true</EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>
    <CompilerGeneratedFilesOutputPath>Generated</CompilerGeneratedFilesOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="CleanSourceGeneratedFiles" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild" DependsOnTargets="$(BeforeBuildDependsOn)">
    <RemoveDir Directories="Generated" />
  </Target>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Generated\**" />
    <Content Include="Generated\**" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Only do this if you want the generated files in your source-controlled directory. They'll get checked in. In some source control systems (i.e. P4) this is disallowed as it would require a read-only file delete. I can't outright say "never use this approach" but there's some bad smells going on here. You shouldn't ordinarily need the emitted files at all let alone have them in SCM.